# Swift Error - extra argument 'option' in call for SimpleAuth

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

Hi I have been battling with a swift error as I cannot match the arguments of an objective-c method

```
    SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", 

       options: ["scope" : "likes"], completion: { 

          (responseObject : NSDictionary!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

          self.accessToken = responseObject["credentials"]["token"]

          ......

    })
```

//error Extra argument 'options' in call

Declared as:

```
  + (void)authorize:(NSString *)provider options:(NSDictionary *)options completion:(SimpleAuthRequestHandler)completion;
```

Code completion is :

```
  SimpleAuth.authorize(<#provider: String!#>, options: <#[NSObject : AnyObject]!#>, completion: <#SimpleAuthRequestHandler!##(AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void#>)
```

I have tried type casting, down casting, declaring as a separate variables, but still cant get it to work.

Any ideas, will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your definition of your completion block. `SimpleAuthRequestHandler` is defined as:

```
typedef void (^SimpleAuthRequestHandler) (id responseObject, NSError *error);
```

But your completion block/closure is defined as:

```
(responseObject : NSDictionary!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
```

You can't just change the type from `id` (`AnyObject` in Swift) to `NSDictionary!` without explicitly casting it. Your call should look something like this:

```
SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", options: ["scope" : "likes"], completion: {
    (responseObject : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

    /* ... */
})
```

You can then make `responseObject` an `NSDictionary` with a cast:

```
var response = responseObject as NSDictionary
```

Comment: Thanks, error went! That error message really threw me. Another came up when attempting to assign the accessToken, yet I broke the self.accessToken up into a 3 step assign with cast. Thanks Again